# Log file is empty in UWP release mode

Tags: uwp

I have created a logger for UWP using StorgaeFile class and DataWriter.In debug, the log file size is 50KB, but in release mode, the file size is 0 KB. My code is,

```
var ptLogFileName = GetLogFileName(prnTicketLogType, ".txt");
            StorageFile ptLogStorageFile = await fileFolderPath.CreateFileAsync(ptLogFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            var stream = await ptLogStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
            {
                using (var printTicketWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream))
                {
                    printTicketWriter.WriteString(GlobalConstants.KEY_COPIES + ":" + copiesVal + Environment.NewLine);
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    
                    await printTicketWriter.StoreAsync();
                    await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                }
                  }
            stream.Dispose();
```

Comment: Have you checked the value that you want to write into the file? Is it null in release mode? I noticed your previous question. Could you please tell me where is the file located?

Comment: Located in C :...\AppData\Local

Comment: So what's the value that you want to write in release mode? Have you checked whether the value is null?

Comment: I write application information write in the log file. value is not null.but file size always 0 KB

Comment: Have you made a breakpoint in that line of code to if the file and the value both exist? That's an interesting behavior so please double-check that.